# Does 'weak' Steinhaus Property imply Steinhaus Property?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, lebesgue-measure

**Steinhaus Property**: A subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is said to have the Steinhaus Property if $A-A$ contains an interval around the origin.

**Weak Steinhaus** A subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is said to have the weak Steinhaus Property if $A-A$ contains an interval.

Does Weak-Steinhaus imply Steinhaus?

1. Countable Sets are neither Steinhaus nor weak Stienhaus.
2. Cantor Set is Steinhaus and any set with positive measure is Steinhaus.
3. Vitali set is not Weak Steinhaus. ($V-V$ has no rationals for any Vitali set $V$).
4. The following is also not weak Steinhaus:

Consider $\mathbb{R}/A$ where $A = \{ r + n\sqrt{2} , r \in \mathbb{Q}, n \in \mathbb{Z} \} $.

Take a selector, say $B$.

Take $A_1 = \{ r + n\sqrt{2}, r \in \mathbb{Q}, 2n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$

Take $A_2 = \{ r + n\sqrt{2},  r \in \mathbb{Q}, (2n+1) \in \mathbb{Z} \}$

Now, it is easy to check that $B + A_1$ and its complement $B+A_2$ are both not weak Steinhaus.

5. Any subset of a set which is not weak Steinhaus is also not weak Steinhaus.

Note that $0 \in A-A$.

Is there a set which is weak Steinhaus but not Steinhaus?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let
$$K:=3\cdot \Bigl\{\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j 4^{-j} \,; \, a_ j \in \{0,1\}\Bigr\}\,$$
be the  middle-half Cantor set.
Observe that $-K=K-1$ (see addendum).  Moreover,
$$(2K)+K=[0,3] \,,$$ since  $ \{0,1,2,3\}=\{0,2\}+\{0,1\}.$

Therefore $A:=K\cup(2K+5)$  is a weak Steinhaus set, since
$$A-A \supset (2K+5)-K=(2K+5)+K-1 =[4,7] \,.$$

$ $

On the other hand, the difference set $$K-K= K+K-1 = 3 \cdot\Bigl\{\sum_{j=1}^\infty b_j 4^{-j} \,; \, b_j \in \{ 0,1,2\}\Bigr\}-1 $$
has zero length.

It follows that $A$ defined above is not a Steinhaus set, since
$$(A-A) \cap (-1,1) \subset (K-K) \cup \bigl((2K+5)-(2K+5)\bigr)= $$ $$=(K-K) \cup 2(K-K) $$
has zero length.

**Addendum:**
$$K-1=3\cdot \Bigl\{\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j 4^{-j} \,; \, a_j \in \{0,1\}\Bigr\}  -3 \sum_{j=1}^\infty  4^{-j} =$$
$$=3\cdot \Bigl\{\sum_{j=1}^\infty (a_j-1) 4^{-j} \,; \, a_j \in \{0,1\}\Bigr\} =3\cdot \Bigl\{\sum_{j=1}^\infty c_j 4^{-j} \,; \, c_j \in \{-1,0\}\Bigr\} =-K \,. $$

Comment: can you explain how $-K = K - 1$. $\frac{3}{4} \in K$ so, $\frac{-1}{4} \in  K-1 = -K$. But $\frac{1}{4} $ is not in $K$?

Comment: $1/4=3(0+\sum_{j=2}^\infty 4^{-j}) \in K$.  I am adding a general explanation to the end of my answer.